# For Redis as a cache in Wagtail, are there extra steps beyond template fragment caching?

Tags: redis, wagtail

I have Redis set up as a cache in Wagtail, as shown in the [docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8/advanced_topics/performance.html), and it is functioning as expected. (I'm using the Redis To Go add-on for Heroku.) My cached template fragments are being cached. But the cache is pretty small -- less than 400K -- and I'm wondering if there are other things (beyond template fragment caching) that I can or should do to increase the contribution that the cache can make to my site's efficiency. I know this is a basic question, but there does not seem to be much documentation about this for Wagtail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard Django template fragment caching is the main way that you can use a cache to improve the performance of Wagtail pages. Menus are often good candidates for fragment caching.

There's an open PR which uses a cache - if available - for image renditions, and should improve the efficiency of image-heavy sites:

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/pull/4883

And this plugin caches whole page responses:

https://docs.coderedcorp.com/wagtail-cache/